# Two truths and a lie

Tags: puzzle

Saw this and I'm not even sure this is a valid question. It seems that A is a lie is true. But I can't wrap my head around the case in which B is a lie. So here it goes:

Two truths and a lie: Which is a lie?
A. This statement
B. Not this statement
C. One of the other statements

Comment: I have been informed on more than one occasion that Mathematics.SE no longer accepts questions that are puzzles. The advice usually given is to post puzzles on other websites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Self-referential statements are tricky: there is no guarantee that any consistent truth values can be assigned.  In particular, statement A says that statement A ("This statement") is a lie.  That can never be assigned a consistent truth value (this is exactly the [Liar's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox))